# full calendar not displaying when loaded (with backbone)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, fullcalendar

I am using the jQuery plugin [full calendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) in conjunction with backbone.js and having an issue where it does not display properly when first loading.

This is my render function for the backbone view containing the calendar:

```
render: function() {

    var that = this;

    // DEBUG:
    // console.log({entries: data});

    this.$el.html(this.template(this.serialize()));

    this.$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },

        height: that.$el.parent().height()
    });

            // prints undefined
    console.log(this.$('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').title);

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        this.$('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView','agendaWeek');
    }, 500);


    return this;
}
```

You can see I have a set timeout for 500 ms included. When I delay that 500 ms, and then change the view to agendaWeek, it will display. However, if I do not delay, the calendar does not show. There are no errors printed in either case.

I am at a loss of what to try here or what might be going wrong. Is there a callback for the creation of the calendar that I am missing somewhere in the docs?

Thanks

EDIT: could it be that the .html() funciton isn't complete and causing an issue?

Comment: Does Fullcalendar perhaps care about the size or position of its element? I've come across possibly similar issues with Google Maps and the `setTimeout(..., 0)` trick worked for me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue is what @muistooshort alluded to. I've used the full calendar plugin and it does care about the "size and position" of it's element.

Comment: Does the issue remain if you hard code the height? What this.serialize() returns?

Comment: this.serialize() should perhaps be this.model.toJSON() ?

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar problem and found this important information in the docs:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/render/

My calendar was on a tab currently not selected making the parent container not visible and thus not drawn correctly. Added a call to the render method after selecting the tab and it all worked great.

Your issue might be solved in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

I am using backbone.js and I too had the same issue.

I was declaring and initializing calendar in `OnRender()` event.

Later to solve this issue I moved the code for declaring and initializing calendar into an `OnShow()` event.

**Issue:**

According to my issue it was because require element was not present on the DOM. `OnShow()` gets fired when your DOM is completely ready.

Finally it worked for me.